# telegram bot api: Bad Request: wrong file_id or the file is temporarily unavailable

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, bad-request, telegram-webhook

**Bad Request: wrong file_id or the file is temporarily unavailable**

Sometimes when I request a file url from Telegram with the getFile method with a telegram bot api, I get this error that I did not find any explanation for it. If you have information, please benefit me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the result of contacting [t.me/BotSupport](https://t.me/BotSupport):

> *I've asked our team to check, they confirmed there is no exact issues with the bot, when getting an error like that, the way to go is to
> retry after a moment, it should be transient and goes away on it's
> own.*

Of course, this is while we were sure that the bot sent a file_id that belongs to itself. (and not a file_id of another bot)

Answer (score 0):

You can download voice file in Java as:

```
 @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        var msg = update.getMessage();
        var voice = msg.getVoice();
        String fieldId = voice.getFileId();
        
        // Create a GetFile request with the provided file ID
        GetFile getFile = new GetFile();
        getFile.setFileId(fileId);

        // Execute the GetFile request
        File file = execute(getFile);

        // Get the file URL returned by the Telegram API
        String fileURL = file.getFileUrl(BOT_ID);

        //Downloading file from URL
        Files.copy(
                    new URL(fileURL).openStream(),
                    Paths.get("voice.oga"));
    ...
```